# Why doesn't time.sleep run in parallel in a Tornado coroutine?

Tags: asynchronous, tornado

When I run this handler in a simple Tornado app and make two requests to it with `curl`, it doesn't run in parallel. It prints out "1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5", when I want it to print "1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5".

```
class SleepHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        for i in range(5):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that `time.sleep` is a **blocking** function: it doesn’t allow control to return to the `IOLoop` so that other handlers can be run.

Of course, `time.sleep` is often just a placeholder in these examples, the point is to show what happens when something in a handler gets slow. No matter what the real code is doing, to achieve concurrency blocking code must be replaced with non-blocking equivalents. This means one of three things:

- *Find a coroutine-friendly equivalent*. For time.sleep, use tornado.gen.sleep instead:

  ```
  class CoroutineSleepHandler(RequestHandler):
      @gen.coroutine
      def get(self):
          for i in range(5):
              print(i)
              yield gen.sleep(1)
  ```

  When this option is available, it is usually the best approach. See the [Tornado wiki](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/wiki/Links) for links to asynchronous libraries that may be useful.
- *Find a callback-based equivalent*. Similar to the first option, callback-based libraries are available for many tasks, although they are slightly more complicated to use than a library designed for coroutines. These are typically used with `tornado.gen.Task` as an adapter:

  ```
  class CoroutineTimeoutHandler(RequestHandler):
      @gen.coroutine
      def get(self):
          io_loop = IOLoop.current()
          for i in range(5):
              print(i)
              yield gen.Task(io_loop.add_timeout, io_loop.time() + 1)
  ```

  Again, the [Tornado wiki](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/wiki/Links) can be useful to find suitable libraries.
- *Run the blocking code on another thread*. When asynchronous libraries are not available, `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` can be used to run any blocking code on another thread. This is a universal solution that can be used for any blocking function whether an asynchronous counterpart exists or not:

  ```
  executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8)

  class ThreadPoolHandler(RequestHandler):
      @gen.coroutine
      def get(self):
          for i in range(5):
              print(i)
              yield executor.submit(time.sleep, 1)
  ```

  See the [Asynchronous I/O chapter](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html) of the Tornado user’s guide for more on blocking and asynchronous functions.

Comment: I wish you could sticky this answer

Comment: That's the idea. This is copied from [the tornado faq](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html#why-isn-t-this-example-with-time-sleep-running-in-parallel) so that all the other questions that ask this can be closed as duplicates of this one.