# How tornado process remote close connection while it is processing handler?

Tags: tornado

I have read tornado `ioloop` and relevant modules to understand what tornado would do when a socket is accepted and a request is parsed and processed.

I want to know if it is possible for tornado to stop request processing after the request connection is closed?

---

I build a test handler, the `get` method spends 5 seconds for sleeping(time.sleeo(5)).

Then I send some requests to tornado, all requests are set read timeout 3 seconds, I found some `close_wait` connections on tornado and several minutes later, these connections are closed normally.

I guess the 5 seconds handler is slow down tornado's event loop, when tornado process the second handler, its connection has been closed, if tornado know that, it does not need to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `time.sleep()` in Tornado applications; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205085/why-doesnt-time-sleep-run-in-parallel-in-a-tornado-coroutine) for why.
2. When the time-consuming part of your handler is non-blocking, you can define a method [`on_connection_close()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.on_connection_close) which will be called when the connection closes. From this method you can cancel the ongoing work. You'll have to implement cancellation yourself, for example by setting `self.cancelled = True` in `on_connection_close`, then checking this attribute periodically during your ongoing asynchronous work.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I have another two questions. 1. My handler is written as blocking, I know that will block ioloop. I checked `socket` state before executing handler: call `recv` on that `socket` with flag `MSG_PEEK`, if I got empty string I think that connection has been closed by remote, if I got EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK exception I know the connection is alive, is this right for me? 2. I want to log every connection accept time, I add log in `accept_handler`, but I find every log output one by one, I think they should be appear at same time.

Comment: The MSG_PEEK trick might work if you're OK with only serving one connection at a time, but keep in mind that it sometimes takes a *long* time for closed connections to be detected. I don't understand your second question (and it's better to ask new questions as new questions instead of as comments).